# PHP: foreach in function with array parameter call

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code and it works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exercitii</title>
    </head>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <?php 
            function no_name($paramOne) { 
                $param = array("mihai", "jon", "michael");
                $param[] = $paramOne; 
                foreach($param as $value) { 
                    echo($value . " sunt cel mai bun " . "<br/>"); 
                } 
            } 
            $string = "dan";
            no_name($string);
        ?> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Output:

```
mihai sunt cel mai bun
jon sunt cel mai bun
michael sunt cel mai bun
dan sunt cel mai bun
```

But how can I add more names like: "costel", "mihaela", "george" to one array and call function with array parameter to further update names?

Comment: Please give me more options

Comment: So you want to add to the array `$param` every time the function is called?

Comment: yes..and add more name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you're trying to pass an array to the function instead of a string? If so, instead of appending to the $param array, you could do an array merge.

```
function no_name(array $paramOne) { 
    $param = array("mihai", "jon", "michael");
    $param = array_merge($param, $paramOne); 
    foreach($param as $value) { 
        echo($value . " sunt cel mai bun " . "<br/>"); 
    } 
} 

no_name(array("dan", "costel", "mihaela", "george"));
```

Comment: Thaks all for your help...and Thanks Vlad your solution is very good

Answer (score 0):

I would just pass the whole array to the function, without hardcoding anything in it.

But if you want to stick with your method, use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
function please_call_me_everything_but_no_name(){

  static $defaults = ['some', 'names'];

  foreach(array_merge($defaults, func_get_args()) as $value){

    // do your stuff

  }

}
```

And you call it as:

```
please_call_me_everything_but_no_name('other', 'words');
```

Comment: If that's really what OP is looking for, I don't get the point of having such a function. By the way +1 "please_call_me_everything_but_no_name"

Comment: how can we use like   foreach(array_merge($defaults, func_get_args())){ ??

Comment: @CodeLover by typing and running it? : PP Try yourself and see what happens, it won't hurt!

Comment: @CodeLover I forgot to add `as $value`, sorry.

Comment: @moonwave99 ur edit makes some sense now ..and it hurts a little by seeing ur first code ..:p

Comment: @DanutMarianGabrian sorry, but here it does not work like that - you don't ask for scripts, you make questions and read related answers, and if there is something you did not understand, you ask for further explanation [and with all chance you'll be given].

Comment: Thaks all for your help...and thanks Vlad your solution is very good.